# Mouse movement accelerates code execution?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm teaching myself how to use OpenGL to create graphics, and I've got a basic spiral script+rotation. The Y-Axis rotation is automatic based on a timer function, but I noticed that when I move my mouse inside the window, it seems to rotate faster than intended. Could someone please look over my script and tell me what is causing the acceleration of the timer function?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// Change viewing volume and viewport. Called when window is resized
void ChangeSize(GLsizei w, GLsizei h)
{
    GLfloat nRange = 100.0f;

    //Prevent a divide by zero
    if(h == 0)
        h = 1;

    // Set Viewport to window dimensions
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    // Reset projection matrix stack
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // Establish clipping volume (left, right, buttom, top, near, far)
    if (w<= h)
        glOrtho (-nRange, nRange, -nRange*h/w, nRange*h/w, -nRange, nRange);
    else
        glOrtho (-nRange*w/h, nRange*w/h, -nRange, nRange, -nRange, nRange);

//Reset Model view matrix stack
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

//Define a constant for pi
#define GL_PI 3.1415f

// This function does all the initialization
void SetupRC()
{
    // Black background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );

    // Set drawing color to green
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}


// Test declaration of rotation angle
GLfloat xRot = 0;
GLfloat yRot = 0;

// Modifiable variables for the eccentricity
    GLfloat xMod = 50.0f;
    GLfloat yMod = 50.0f;

// Called to draw scene
void RenderScene(void)
{
    GLfloat x,y,z,angle; // Storage for coordinates and angles
    GLfloat sizes[2]; // Store supported point size range
    GLfloat step; // Store point size increments
    GLfloat curSize; //Store current point size
    // Get supported point size range and step size
    glGetFloatv(GL_POINT_SIZE_RANGE, sizes);
    glGetFloatv(GL_POINT_SIZE_GRANULARITY, &step);

//Set the initial point size
curSize = sizes[0];

// Clear the window with current clearing color
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// Save matrix state and do the rotation
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(xRot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(yRot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

// specify point size before primitive is specified
glPointSize(curSize);

//Call only once for remaining points
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);

//Set beginning z coordinate
z = -50.0f;

//Loop around in a circle three times
for (angle = 0.0f; angle <= (2.0f*GL_PI)*3.0f; angle += 0.1f)
{
    // Calculate x and y values on the circle (the major and minor axis)
    x = xMod*sin(angle);
    y = yMod*cos(angle);
    // Specify the point and move the z value up a little
    glVertex3f(x, y, z);
    z += 0.5f;
}

// Done drawing points
glEnd();




// Restore transformations
glPopMatrix();

//Flush drawing commands
glFlush();
}

// Modifier Code
void CircleController (int key, int x, int y)
    {
 switch (key) 
{    
   case 27 :      break;

   case 100 : 

               (yRot -= 5.0f);  ;  break;

   case 102 :  

               (yRot += 5.0f);  ;  break;

   case 101 :  

               (xRot -= 5.0f);  ;  break;

   case 103 :    

               (xRot += 5.0f);  ;  break;
glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
}

}

void MouseHandler (int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    // Holder variable assigned to overcome printf limitation and prevent double-    printing due to MouseUp function call
    GLfloat Holder = xMod;
    // Increases size, and decreases timer speed by increasing the amount of time     needed.
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
        {
                xMod+= 5.0f;

    }

        // Decreases size, and increases timer speed by decreasing the amount of     time needed.
    if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
        {
            xMod-= 5.0f ;

    }

    if (Holder != xMod)
        printf("%d \n", Holder);

}

void TimerFunction(int value)
{
    //Call the arrow key function
    glutSpecialFunc(CircleController);

    //Call the Mouseclick Modifier function
    glutMouseFunc(MouseHandler);

     if (xRot < 360)
    (xRot += 1.0f);
    else
    (xRot = 0.0f);


    // Redraw the scene with new coordinates
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(1.6666f, TimerFunction, 1);

}



void main(void)
{
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutCreateWindow("Drawing Lines");
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
    glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
    glutTimerFunc(1.6666f, TimerFunction, 1);
    SetupRC();

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem when I was working in opengl a few years ago. I never found a solution for it, but I thought it might be good to know that at least you aren't alone! My personal theory was always that it had something to do with the window focus and which program is given more CPU time, but that's just pure speculation.

Comment: Why are you passing `1.6666f` to a function expecting an `unsigned int`?

Comment: I did notice a difference in execution speed versus how much ram/how much of my CPU was being used. If I had photoshop or Firefox with Facebook open, my code seemed to spaz out and execute rapidly as well. Odd stuff would happen if I changed the battery settings on my laptop too. OpenGL does strange things. Also, I think I misinterpreted the parameters from the book with that. Mooing duck, I think you may have found the issue. I changed it to an integer and it seems to be operating just fine now, thank you alot! Can you explain the erratic behavior? Or do you just know what caused it?

Comment: Also, I don't know if this is related, but usually `sin` goes with `y`, and `cos` with `x`.

Comment: "Also, I don't know if this is related, but usually sin goes with y, and cos with x" Updated, didn't drastically change anything, but thanks for the tip, it's probably good practice to align my functions with the proper axis.

Comment: @Kain: realistically the only thing that would affect is the starting position and rotation direction.  So nobody would notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Eric Palace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2525797/eric-palace) gave me the start

> My personal theory was always that it had something to do with the window focus and which program is given more CPU time, but that's just pure speculation.

That makes sense to me.  But wait, don't you only paint on a timer?  Wouldn't that prevent additional CPU time from modifying movement speed?  Yes you do.  Sortof.

```
glutTimerFunc(1.6666f, TimerFunction, 1);
```

The doc's for [glutTimerFunc](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node64.html) say that the first parameter is an `unsigned int`, representing the timer in milliseconds.  So you're telling glut "call this function every 1 millsecond." (Approx 1000FPS)  And since it takes longer than one millisecond to execute, you're effectively telling it "run this function over and over as fast as you possibly can".  Which it does.  And so additional CPU time *is* making a difference.

To avoid situtations like this (aside from correcting the 1.6666f parameter), it's usually suggested to

- update the "world" in separate functions from painting the screen.  In fact, I would imagine it to be common to have *two or more* world update functions.  One for stuff that needs updating with the paint: arrows and running characters, one for stuff that only changes once a second or so: mana regen and npc decisions, and one for really slow stuff: respawns.
- During an "update", check how much time has passed since the last update, (maxing out at half a second or so), and make the world update *that much*.  Then if updates run twice as often or half as often for any reason, the game doesn't appear to speed up or slow down, you just just more/fewer frames instead.

Here's what such an update might look like

```
radians xrot = 0; //use a units class
radians rot_per_second = .01;

void updateFrame(double time_passed) {
     assert(time_passed>=0 && time_passed <= 1.0);
     radians rotate_thistime = rot_per_second * time_passed;
     xrot += rotate_thistime;
}

void do_updates() {
     static clock_t lastupdatetime = clock()-1; //use openGL functions instead of C
     clock_t thisupdatetime = clock();
     double seconds = double(thisupdatetime-lastupdatetime)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
     if (seconds > 0.5) //if something happened and haven't update in a long time
         seconds = 0.5; //pretend only half a second passed.
     //this can happen if
     //   computer is overloaded
     //   computer hibernates
     //   the process is debugged
     //   the clock changes
     if (seconds <= 0.0) //computer is REALLY fast or clock changed
         return; //skip this update, we'll do it when we have sane numbers

     updateFrame(seconds);
     lastupdatetime = thisupdatetime;
}
```

Comment: Yea, the reason I specifically chose that number was to have the program process at 60 "FPS" (Really renders-per-second). The timing isn't too crucial, I just wanted it to flow.

Comment: @Kain: You miscalculated. your code says to update at 600 FPS, but due to rounding it's trying to do 1000 FPS.

Comment: Also, one thing to note is that big blockbuster movies are _still_ shot at a mere 24 FPS.  Video game consoles like XBox and PS3 usually run around 30 FPS.  Very few computer games really run at 60FPS.  So if you thought your video games looked good, then you now know that 24-30FPS is fine for whatever you're doing as well.

Comment: In your second bullet point, what do you mean exactly? I understand the last sentence perfectly, but I am having difficulty understanding it from a programming standpoint.

NinjaEdit: Oh god you're right, my math way WAAAAY off on the refresh time. Sorry :\
And so you say I should shoot for 30 frames?

Comment: @Kain: I reworded that sentence, and added a sample with lots of comments.  Shooting for 60 is fine, but if you have to fall back down to 30 or something, just be aware that that is 100% OK and the game isn't ruined.  It was just a note.

Comment: @Kain: [here's a simple radians class](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4f6e8e2dfb42e590f057133166c81eef-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51)

Comment: I think what @Mooing Duck is referring to is how to manage dynamic timesteps. For example if you take static int firsttime each frame and subtract it from the current time, then multiply that times a factor of how fast things should be going, you can get speeds / etc working correctly for dynamic length frames. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/fixed-time-step-vs-variable-time-step